# Fourier Transform Identities

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals

We know the below,

$$
\mathscr{F}\big\{x(t)\big\}=X(f) \tag{1}
$$
$$
\mathscr{F}\big\{x(-t)\big\}=X(-f) \tag{2}
$$
$$
\mathscr{F}\big\{x^*(t)\big\}=X^*(-f) \tag{3}
$$

Now, if for some signal

$$
x(-t)=x^*(t) \tag{4}
$$

Then, is it safe to assume the following?

$$
X(-f)=X^*(-f) \tag{5}
$$

or does it depend on the type of signal?

Comment: You can still validate the most appropriate answer

Answer (score 13):

You are correct. Your last equation is simply a fancy way of saying that $X(f)$ is real valued.

In general: if it's real in one domain, it's conjugate symmetric in the other.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if eqs. (2) and (3) hold for any "type of signal" (which they do), then (5) must hold.

Inserting (4) into (2) we get
$$
\mathscr{F}\big\{x^*(t)\big\} = X(-f)
$$
and using (3)
$$
X(-f) = X^*(-f)
$$

If we substitute $f = - g$ we get
$$
X(g) = X^*(g)
$$
which, as [Hilmar has already observed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/41468/1606), means that $X(f)$ is real-valued. This is to be expected as, according to (4), $x(t)$ exhibits the [conjugate complex symmetry](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8716/1606).

Answer (score 7):

The answers by @Deve and @Hilmar are technically perfect. I would like to provide some additional insights, with a few questions.

First, do you know of a signal satisfying this **reversed-time/conjugate identity**:

$$x(−t)=x^*(t)\,?$$

A first obvious  idea is to choose among  real and symmetric signals. A natural one in the Fourier framework is the **cosine**.

Now, let us get a little more complex (pun intented).

So second, **what about the real sine**? It is anti-symmetric. But if you remember that $i^*=-i$, the function $t\to i.\sin t$ also becomes a solution as well. So, by additivity, the function

$$t\to e^{i t}$$

(called **complex exponential or cisoid**) **is also a solution**. And its Fourier transform (as a generalized function) is indeed real (albeit somehow "infinite"). Going further, any linear combination of **cisoids** with real coefficients will do it.

Your question illustrates how Fourier duality is important, and how using it can  simplify some issues. As seen in [SYMMETRY OF THE DTFT FOR REAL SIGNALS](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Symmetry_DTFT_Real_Signals.html):

> In other terms, if a signal $ x(n)$ is real, then its spectrum is Hermitian (``conjugate symmetric'').

Here, your base signal $x$ is Hermitian, and the Fourier version is real. So to understand it better, just imagine $t$ is a frequency variable, and $f$ is its time dual. The standard representation is provided in [Digital Analysis of Geophysical Signals and Waves/Complex Symmetry Properties](http://dagsaw.sdsu.edu/3.3.html).

[image: Complex Symmetry Properties]

It is also called the [Heyser corkscrew/spiral](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/51796/15892).