# Is Discrete cosine transform Translational Invariant

Tags: mfcc, dct

I am using 2D Mellin-Cepstrum to extract features,

1. If I use log-polar transform to get rotational invariance, the rotation is transformed to translation. Can I use DCT next to get translational invariance. Is DCT translational Inavriant?
   This will help me get rotation, translational invariance and also give compact representation.
2. Is there any way other than using FFT, to compensate for the translation?

Comment: [Scattering](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076) might be of interest; translation + rotation invariance. DCT is not translation invariant.