# What are some speech features that vary with what the speaker says?

Tags: speech-processing, mfcc

I have been working on a text-dependent speaker verification project. I have used mel-frequency cepstrum coefficients(MFCC) for the project. As far as I know, MFCC coefficients depend on the vocal characteristics of the speaker, not what he/she says. What features can be extracted from speech that rely both on the speaker's vocal characteristics and what he/she says?

Comment: basically everything that you would reasonably call a speech feature would change depending on what is spoken. Otherwise, it's little use to call it "speech feature", i.e. a distinguishing property within the class of speech.

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076); also see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6763).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: You are correct, but I think what M. Fahmin means is a combination of *voice* features and text-dependent speech features as a function of those voice features (i.e. "the speaker"). I will try and put an answer together.

Answer (score 0):

MFCC *does* contain plenty of information about what is being spoken. This is assuming that the time-resolution is on the order of the length of phones (10-100 ms), and that the number of coefficients is still reasonable (13-40). In fact, this feature representation is one of the most common for keyword spotting, automated speech recognition, et.c.